# Sound coming from both speakers and headphones on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, sound, headphones, speakers

Occasionally while I'm listening to something on my headphones I'll notice that the sound is coming out of my speakers as well. It doesn't happen all of the time.  I am running Ubuntu 14.04 on a Dell Inspiron 15-3521.  There are other questions about this same issue but as far as I can tell they are all on 12.04.

What I've tried

1. Manually muting the speakers in alsamixer as a temporary fix
2. Downloading gnome-alsamixer to use the headphone jack sense option, but apparently that doesn't exist anymore.

Any help would be appreciated

%% update 4/14/15

I found that when i'm having the issue, if I go to my sound settings and look at the output tab, it shows "play sound through speakers" and does not switch to "play sound through headphones" when I plug in the headphones.

When it is working properly, it does switch to "play sound through headphones"

Answer (score 2):

In Alsa mixer, under "Auto Mute" tab change the selection to "Line out"
It must have been "Disabled" before. Worked for me.

Comment: Thanks. I have a hard time verifying that this is a solution because as I mentioned the problem only occasionally happens.  Right now, even if I disable Auto Mute my speakers still turn off when I plug in my headphones.

Comment: I can't seem to find this "Auto Mute" tab that everyone seems to be seeing.